Block sender on iCloud email
Is there a way to entirely block incoming mail from a specific sender, on the server side?
I have set up a rule on icloud.com where all mail from their address go to Trash. But that means the mail will still end up on all my devices. Occasionally, I take a look at the trash folder in the app on my iPhone or Mac, and will find a barrage of unwanted email.
I want to prevent this email reaching any of my devices.
Setting a delete rule on my Mac locally isn’t enough, as that will only trigger when I open the Mail app on my Mac.
thank you.
